Control text opacity based on scroll using javascript
I have a div with two spans inside it. The position of spans is that span1 uses a sticky position from the center of the div while span2 is at the bottom of the div. The idea is that, as the user scrolls, span1, which is initially at opacity 0 becomes visible and after further scrolling, span2 becomes visible. I tried achieving this by manually tweaking the points they become visible. Is there an optimal way to achieve this? I am attaching my code as reference


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const message = document.querySelector('.message');
  const deathSpan = document.querySelector('.message > span');
  const vhDiv = document.querySelector('.vh');

  const rect = message.getBoundingClientRect();
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;


  const fadeStart1 = windowHeight * 0.3;
  const fadeEnd1 = windowHeight * 0.6;


  const fadeStart2 = windowHeight * 0.5;
  const fadeEnd2 = windowHeight * 0.9;


  if (rect.top <= fadeEnd1 && rect.bottom >= fadeStart1) {
    let opacity1 = (fadeEnd1 - rect.top) / (fadeEnd1 - fadeStart1);
    opacity1 = Math.min(Math.max(opacity1, 0), 1);
    deathSpan.style.opacity = opacity1;
  } else {
    deathSpan.style.opacity = 0;
  }


  if (rect.top <= fadeEnd2 && rect.bottom >= fadeStart2) {
    let opacity2 = (fadeEnd2 - rect.top) / (fadeEnd2 - fadeStart2);
    opacity2 = Math.min(Math.max(opacity2, 0), 1);
    vhDiv.style.opacity = opacity2;
  } else {
    vhDiv.style.opacity = 0;
  }
});
.above-divs a{
font-size:10rem;
background-color: black;
color: white;

}


.message {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  align-items: center;
}

.message span {
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.message>span {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.vh {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
<div class="above-divs">
  <a href="">hello</a>
</div>



<div class="message">
  <span>Text1 (span1)</span>
  <div class="vh">
    <span>Text2 (span2)</span>
  </div>
</div>




Indeed IntersectionObserver is the way, but you don't need to specify one for each element
Your HTML/CSS structure is a bit weird but I more or less followed it for a working example


const options = {
  // Root to defaults if not specified
  //root: document.querySelector("#myParentArea"),
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 1.0,
};
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
        entry.target.style.opacity = 1;
      } else {
        entry.target.style.opacity = 0;
      }
    });
  }, options);
  
  observer.observe(span1);
  observer.observe(span2);
.above-divs a{
  font-size:10rem;
}

.message {
  margin-top:30rem
}

.message span {
  font-size: 10vw;
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

.vh{
  padding-top:10rem
 }
<div class="above-divs">
  <a href="">hello</a>
</div>



<div class="message">
  <span id='span1'>Text1 (span1)</span>
  <div class="vh">
    <span id='span2'>Text2 (span2)</span>
  </div>
</div>




This might be useful: Intersection Observer API MDN
This API provides an efficient way to track visibility changes of elements relative to the viewport.
You can try doing something like:
// Target elements
  const span1 = document.querySelector('.message > span');
  const span2 = document.querySelector('.vh > span');

  // Fade-in observer for span1 (centered/sticky)
  const observer1 = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) { // If more than half of the span is visible
        span1.style.opacity = 1;
      } else {
        span1.style.opacity = 0;
      }
    });
  }, observerOptions);

  // Fade-in observer for span2 (at the bottom)
  const observer2 = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) { // Same logic for span2
        span2.style.opacity = 1;
      } else {
        span2.style.opacity = 0;
      }
    });
  }, observerOptions);

  // Observe the target elements
  observer1.observe(span1);
  observer2.observe(span2);
});

